# Laravel 5 / AngularJS CORS Issue

Tags: angularjs, html, laravel, google-chrome

**Issues:**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/create/user. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I have tried using Cors.php middleware & public/index.php & many more solutions from stackoverflow but none of this working.

> header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
>   header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE,
>   OPTIONS'); header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type,
>   X-Auth-Token');

Comment: We can't tell why your attempts to implement CORS are not working, you haven't provided a [mcve] (and the code you have provided is marked as a quotation instead of code for some reason).

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to do this cross origin in the first place. Just pick `example.com` or `www.example.com` and host everything there. Having the same site on two different hostnames (one with `www` and one without) is silly (and more effort!).

Comment: Just forgot to set www before example.com. Sorry for that but till now it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will have to define every route for OPTIONS method, and make them through the middleware you made.
Or you need to update Laravel core class function.

Please refer the answer here:

[CORS issue for Angular + Laravel project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306481/cors-issue-for-angular-laravel-project/41306660#41306660)